# ASP page errors when viewing page in Terminal Services Server

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, terminal-services

The following really has me baffled.

I have a website written in classic ASP. The site has a side bar navigation menu that is built dynamically by getting a list of URLs from a stored procedure and listing them in a table. The site is working fine on my computer.

But we have a call center and those employees use a terminal server to get to our webpage. Today several of them (but not all of them) began complaining that some of the sidebar links would redirect them back to our home page instead of where the link should go.

I checked, the issue is real, the links are correct, in fact typing the link in by hand results in the same issue. However it is not on every computer using the terminal server, on some machines it is fine.

So I check further, if I go to the same terminal server the page is much worse. Big chunks are missing, in fact the sidebar does not display at all, it looks like it would if there were an error in the asp code (chunks of generated page not displaying after an error is encountered).

If I use remote desktop to go to a different server and browse to our website using that the page is fine, so whatever it is it is unique to the terminal server (as opposed to being unique to remote desktop sessions).

The browser being used is IE 10, although I don't think the browser could be the issue, I can't easily install another one to test.

Does anyone have an idea as to what could cause this?

Edit to Add:
I installed Firefox on the terminal server and the same page renders fine. I viewed source and saved it to a file in both Firefox and IE, the generated source at the browser is identical yet it never loads properly in IE, on my computer but is fine in Firefox or on other computers using the same Terminal Server and IE.

Comment: If your problem is specific to one machine then I don't see how it could be with asp code which is executed server side.  I've come across a couple of cases of old web pages not rendering correctly in IE10 and in both cases clicking the compatibility button fixed it.

Comment: Most likely culprits: 1> An IE zone/security setting is different on the terminal server, or 2> You have a connectivity problem between your terminal server and the web server. You might troubleshoot the latter by running Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've added some additional info above.

Comment: Have you tried the compatibility button.  Alternatively there's a meta tag you can use to emulate earlier versions of IE, eg <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Internet Explorer had javascript turned off by default. I had not thought of that at first, but sure enough....